# How do I refer to the two types of loading screen?

Tags: rendering, terminology, loading

I'm troubleshooting some issues beyond the scope of this forum, and I'd like to be able to talk about certain parts of the gaming experience, specifically the two types of loading screen I see in Prey.

Both are shown in [this short video I made](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-2VQpaRY5k4).

The first type with the loading bar is what I usually think of as the "loading screen", but what do I call the second "loading screen" that happens right after with the moving squares in the bottom-right? To be clear, I'd like a term to be used with non-game-devs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first is a classic "progress bar", or when it's specifically to visualize loading, a "loading bar".

UI designers call the second a "loading spinner". Or when it's not spinning but doing something else, a "loading indicator". It's useful to visualize to the user that something is still happening in the background when you don't have any means to estimate how long that process will take.

Comment: [As Kirby Ferguson says, "The opposite of Progress Bars is Spinning Stuff"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=24vYoso8Af0)